# How to make the computer "click" buttons?

Tags: java, button, swt

I am writing a tic tac toe program in java swt, and am trying to figure out how to make the computer "click" on a button to display the X/O. Any suggestions?

Comment: By computer, do you mean the actual computer like we're using right now, or do you mean a computer-controlled player? For the latter, you probably don't need to have it 'click' buttons, since you control the logic of the code. The AI player can just send commands to your game controller.

Comment: I don't need the mouse to move or anything, just need the buttons to automatically change to display the x/o.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for the [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class. With this, you can move the mouse around and have it click.

Answer (score 1):

See [`Robot.mousePress(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#mousePress%28int%29) for activating the button.

Answer (score 1):

First you gotta move your mouse to the button location and then press and release the mouse button:

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.mouseMove(500, 340); //Assuming this is the button location.
r.mousePress( InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK );
r.mouseRelease( InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK );
```